# find parent id and child id based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a sample dataframe

```
id    mobile_number    to_be_deleted
 1       123                0
 2       123                1
 3       123                1
 4       456                0
 5       789                0
 6       789                1
 7       1234               0
 8       789                1
```

Considering the rows that contain `to_be_deleted` values as `0`, those record's ids will be parent_id, and the same mobile_number in anthoer records would be child's id.

I'm expecting to summarize the above dataframe to

```
parent_id       child_id
    1              2, 3
    4              null
    5              6, 8
    7              null
```

What could be the best way to summarize the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `join` as `aggfunc`. Note that we also need to use `astype(str)` so that we can concatenate numbers:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['mobile_number'], columns = df['to_be_deleted'].astype(str),\
       values=df['id'].astype(str), aggfunc= lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

Output:

```
       to_be_deleted    0   1
mobile_number       
123                    1    2, 3
1234                   7    NaN
456                    4    NaN
789                    5    6, 8
```

Comment: Nice one, I like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as follows.

We start by applying the following custom function

```
df_new = df[df['to_be_deleted'] == 0].groupby('mobile_number')['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

[Out]:
   mobile_number id
0            123  1
1            456  4
2            789  5
3           1234  7
```

And to obtain the correct `parent_id` column there's still one thing to do: rename column `id` to `parent_id`. For that one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) as follows

```
df_new.rename(columns={'id': 'parent_id'}, inplace=True)

[Out]:
   mobile_number parent_id
0            123         1
1            456         4
2            789         5
3           1234         7
```

Now, with the `parent_id` ready, all one has to do is to tweak the `mobile_number` column to obtain the `child_id`. For that one can use the following custom function

```
df_new['child_id'] = df_new['mobile_number'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df[(df['mobile_number'] == x) & (df['to_be_deleted'] == 1)]['id'].astype(str)))

[Out]:
   mobile_number parent_id child_id
0            123         1      2,3
1            456         4         
2            789         5      6,8
3           1234         7
```

Finally, as one doesn't want the column `mobile_number`, one can remove it with [`pandas.DataFrame.pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) as

```
df_new.pop('mobile_number')

[Out]:
  parent_id child_id
0         1      2,3
1         4         
2         5      6,8
3         7
```

---

There's room to wrap everything in a function as follows

```
def summarization(df):

    df_new = df[df['to_be_deleted'] == 0].groupby('mobile_number')['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

    df_new.rename(columns={'id': 'parent_id'}, inplace=True)

    df_new['child_id'] = df_new['mobile_number'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(df[(df['mobile_number'] == x) & (df['to_be_deleted'] == 1)]['id'].astype(str)))

    df_new.pop('mobile_number')

    return df_new
```

And then all one has to do is to apply the function to the dataframe

```
df_new = summarization(df)

[Out]:
  parent_id child_id
0         1      2,3
1         4         
2         5      6,8
3         7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two aggs for to_be_deleted == 0, and for == 1 and then outer merge them.

```
childs = df[df.to_be_deleted == 1].groupby('mobile_number').agg(child_id=('id', list))
parents = df[df.to_be_deleted == 0].groupby('mobile_number').agg(parent_id=('id', 'first'))
out = parents.merge(childs, on='mobile_number', how='outer')
```

print(out):

```
   mobile_number  parent_id child_id
0            123          1   [2, 3]
1            456          4      NaN
2            789          5   [6, 8]
3           1234          7      NaN
```